# Multiple Class Based Views at one URL

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I'd like to use two different CBVs under one url - depending on a user's permissions. The views are quite different, and I do not want to blend the two views into just one.

What would be a good approach for this? I am thinking of something like this:

```
class View1(TemplateView):
   ...

class View2(TemplateView):
   ...

def unified_view(request):
    if request.user.has_perm('...'):  # here I could decide which CBV to use
        return View1
    return View2
```

`unified_view` would be used in the app's `urls.py` and decides which CBV to use. Obviously `return View1` does not work. What would be the correct call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you need to return

```
View1.as_view()
```

Comment: Almost. I continued playing around. using `View1.as_view()(request)` works for me. If the function based view has parameters, I guess, I would need to use `View1.as_view()(request, *args, **kwargs)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommand you to do this, class based view should be simple and do one thing.

If you have to do this, you can override `get_context_data` or `get_template_names` of TemplateView for different users.

Comment: "simple and do one thing" is the exact reason why I have two different CBVs: one for users having a certain permission, and one for the other users.